# java.lang.Class and equality

Tags: java

According the javadoc of `Class`

> Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class
>   object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and
>   number of dimensions.

But when I run the below

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2 };
out.println(intArray.getClass().hashCode());
int[] int2Array = { 1, 2 };
out.println(int2Array.getClass().hashCode());

out.println(intArray.equals(int2Array));
```

I get the below output

```
1641745
1641745
false
```

I am wondering why the equals is returning false even though both the arrays are of `int` type and have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you're calling [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) on the array instances themselves instead of their `Class` object. Try:

```
out.println(intArray.getClass().equals(int2Array.getClass())); //prints true
```

You could also write:

```
out.println(int[].class.equals(int[].class)); //prints true thankfully
```

As an aside, matching hash codes don't necessarily indicate equality, though that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3):

try to call `intArray.getClass().equals(int2Array.getClass())`

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Java hash code contract only requires that:

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an    execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

(From [the Java documentation on `Object#hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29))

Here you have two integer arrays that are not equal (e.g. `a.equals(b) => false`), but they are *not* (see the third point) required to return unequal hashcodes.

---

Also, note that your code will work if you use [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) instead of [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), as follows.  Note that [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) checks that "both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal."

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2 };
out.println(intArray.getClass().hashCode());
int[] int2Array = { 1, 2 };
out.println(int2Array.getClass().hashCode());

out.println(Arrays.equals(intArray, int2Array));
```

See http://www.ideone.com/HaysD for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two different arrays. Array equality is based on identity, not array content. Since they are not the same array, the result is false.

If you want to test the content of two arrays for equality, there are helper methods in `java.util.Arrays`.

```
out.println(Arrays.equals(intArray, int2Array);
```

Comment: There's also the Arrays.deepEquals methods if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of `equals()` is defined by [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

When you compare two arrays using `equals()`, theis default method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Run this and the answer will be clear:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2 };

System.out.println("array1.hashcode: " + array1.hashCode());
System.out.println("array2.hashcode: " + array2.hashCode());
System.out.println("array1.class.hashcode: " + array1.getClass().hashCode());
System.out.println("array2.class.hashcode: " + array2.getClass().hashCode());
```